# Magento - Send order email on status Not paid

Tags: magento, sendmail

does anybody know how to trigger the order email in magento when the order is not paid?
I have a payment provider (multisafepay) and their first step after the checkout creates the order with the status Not Paid. At this point the order email is not send. Only in the step after this the order email is send (paid status)

The problem is that sometimes people go to the first step, then think hey I need more or do not have money and go back to the site, the order is created but no notification has been send out. For a lot of items we only have 1 in stock so they cannot order again.

Thanks

Comment: You ask and answer on the same place?? What you realy need?